# fastest way for replacing i-th occurance in a string

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, replace

I have a string which consists of total n equal substrings. For example, string `"hellooo dddd"` has 3 `"dd"` substrings (I say it has occured 3 times). In a more general case which we have n equal substrings in a string, how can I replace i-th occurance in the string. A ,method like `replace()` for i-th substring. I want to implement it in my android code. (English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.).

Comment: use String.indexOf(value,fromIndex) iteratively

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String replace(String input, String pattern, int occurence, String replacement){
    String result = input; 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern); 
    Matcher m = p.matcher(result); 
    if(occurence == 0){ 
        return result; 
    } else if(occurence == 1){
        m.find();
        result = result.substring(0,m.start()) + replacement + result.substring(m.end());
    } else { 
        m.find();
        int counter = 1; 
        try { 
            while((counter<occurence)&&m.find(m.start()+1)){
                counter++; 
            }
            result = result.substring(0,m.start()) + replacement + result.substring(m.end());
        } catch(IllegalStateException ise){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are not this many occurences of the pattern in the String."); 
        }
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Seems to do something similar to what you want if I understand correctly.

Using the matcher/pattern system it's open to much more complex regex.